# Copy cells if specific text is found

Tags: vba, excel

I seem to have a problem and currently have not found a solution to it, which is why I address this question to you:

Each day I have a list of invoices and orders coming from different suppliers, and the orders are based on part numbers and types.
This list is imported as text and then goes through a macro I made, to arrange everything in cells.
I also need to go through some steps to format this list based on the type of order (ex: windshield, carpets, wheels, etc ). what I usually do is to filter everything and select the order type that I am interested, and then copy on the same row cells with text and formulas from another worksheet, named "template", which is a list of conditions .
Since it varies from day to day, it may not necessarily contain all part types, which is I couldn't use a macro, and I have to continue by hand, and sometimes the list exceeds 200-300 lines.
To give you an example, if E2 has "windshield" I copy in M2 to Q2 a selection of cells from "Template" (M2 to Q2), if "carpets" I copy M3 to Q3, and so on. the list of conditions is around 15 - 20 rows, and sometimes 2 conditions may apply (if order exceeds $5000 I mark it red, if overdue I bold everything, etc) but mainly I copy based on text in coll E.
If this could be copied into a macro, I would really appreciate it, as I need to take some steps every time, like auto-fit, copy header, format the amounts as number (from text), change text color based on order type, etc, and this too takes time.
I hope this information is enough to make an idea about this, and if not, I could post an example of the list I have to work with.
Many thanks in advance for your support

Comment: [tl;dr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read)

Answer (score 0):

Use Application.Worksheetfunction.Match to find in which row in Template the to-be-copied cells can be found, then copy range M-Q for this row and paste in your file

Answer (score 0):

You are asking too much in one question to get help here.  We are best at single issue questions.  The text and code below is intended you give you some ideas.  If your code does not work, post the relevant part here and explain the difference between what it does and what you want it to do.

The problems you mention do not sound difficult. I would expect basic VBA to be enough to get you started. Are you looking for bits of relevant code without learning VBA. If you are, this is a big mistake. Search the web for "Excel VBA tutorial" or visit a large library and review their Excel VBA Primers. There are many tutorials and books to choose from so select one that is right for you. The time spent learning the basics will quickly repay itself.

```
Dim RowCrnt As Long
Dim RowLast As Long

With Worksheets("xxxx")
  RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Row
  For RowCrnt = 2 to RowLast
    ' Code to process each row goes here
  Next
End With
```

The above is probably the structure of your code. The For loop will examine each row in turn which will allow you to take relevant actions.

I have used "E" as a column letter because your question suggests column "E" is the most important. However, code that references columns in this way can be very confusing.  Worse, if the column positions change, you will have to work carefully through your code changing the column letters.  Better to have some statements at the top like this:

```
Const ColDate As String = "A"
Const ColAmtInv As string = "B"
Const ColAmtPaid As string = "C"
Const ColProdType As String = "E"
```

With these constants every reference to a column uses a name not a letter.  The code is easier to read and, if a column moves, one change to the constant statement will fix the problem.

The `Select Case` statement is useful:

```
Select Case .Cells(RowCrnt, ColProdType).Value
  Case "carpets"
    ' code for carpets
  Case "windshield"
    ' code for carpets
  Case Else
    ' Unknown product type
    .Cells(RowCrnt, ColProdType).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Select
```

You can have a string of `If` statements so multiple actions can occur on a single row:

```
If DateAdd("m", 1, .Cells(RowCrnt,ColDate).Value) < Now() And _
   .Cells(RowCrnt,ColAmtInv).Value) > .Cells(RowCrnt,ColAmtPaid).Value Then
  ' Invoice overdue
  .Rows(RowCrnt).Font.Bold = True
End If

If .Cells(RowCrnt,ColAmtInv).Value) > 5000 Then
  ' Large invoice 
  .Rows(RowCrnt).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

You do not have to write the entire macro in one go.  If most action is because of the product type then try that first.

Hope this helps get you started.